# zsh wrapper: how to add prefix to the shell command parameters?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

For example, I have defined a zsh-script called "myCmd.sh"
when I run

```
myCmd --op1 "/p1/p2" --op2 "/p3/p4" -op3 "a"
```

it should actually call

```
Cmd --op1 "/mnt/d/p1/p2" --op2 "/mnt/d/p3/p4" -op3 "a"
```

In other words, **once a path string occurred** in the command parameters, the prefix "/mnt/d" will be added, the cmd and other args or parameters will remain the same.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: `zsh` doesn't necessarily know which argument should have `/mnt/d` prefixed to them. Only `cmd` treates arguments prefixed with `--` as "special".

Comment: How do we recognize a _path string_? In your example, the parameter _a_ after `-op3` could also be a path. Perhaps you mean an **absolute** path, i.e. a parameter starting with a `/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use static named directories to have filename expansion produce the desired path, saving you a little typing. For example,

```
d=/mnt/d

cmd --opt1 ~d/p1/p2 --op2 ~d/p3/p4
```

is the same as

```
cmd --opt1 /mnt/d/p1/p2 --op2 /mnt/d/p3/p4
```

`~name`, where `name` is any parameter with a value that starts with `/`, is expanded to the value of the parameter.

An example:

```
% echo ~d
zsh: no such user or named directory
% d=/mnt/d
% echo ~d
/mnt/d
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, but how about the number of the arguments, because I don't know how much "path" will be given in the command line and I want to replace them all

Comment: You shouldn't need to care about the number. The idea is that the *caller* (aided by filename expansion) provides the correct paths, rather than requiring you to duplicate much or all of `cmd`'s command-line parsing in order to identify which arguments should have a path prefixed to them.

Comment: Unless you are OK with prefixing *any* argument beginning with `/` with `/mnt/d`, regardless of context: then you can simply use `cmd "${@//\//\/mnt\/d\/}"`.